# iTunes keeps resetting my file paths on new external drive

Tags: itunes

Been fighting itunes as I've moved my library from an external Drive on an XP machine to an external drive on a Vista machine.

On the VISTA machine, I've fixed the external drive to Z:

My copied iTunes library is at z:\itunes

I've moved all my music to z:\itunes\itunes music

I've launched iTunes (with SHIFT key), picked the new library, and then reset the music folder to point at the above.

Alas, iTunes still think's all my songs are on a K: drive.

I've then quit iTunes, opened the XML library file, replaced all the paths to point at the Z: drive, saved, then relaunched. If I then immediately quit iTunes, then open the XML file, I see that iTunes went ahead and reset everything back tot he K: drive.

Anyone see a way to get around this? Any idea where iTunes is storing this 'K:' drive info?

Answer (score 1):

The file `iTunes Library.itl` stores your library information; the XML file is generated from this.

Perhaps try running the command `subst K: Z:\` to make K: an alias for the Z:\ drive, then in iTunes open Preferences and on the advanced screen change your library path to Z:\

Next, either go to File → Library → Organize Library and select "Consolidate Library", or turn on "Keep iTunes media folder organized" under Advanced in Preferences.

Comment: I do tell iTunes to point at Z: in preferences. Alas, it won't reset the file paths already in the library. Seems like I need to manually edit the itl file somehow...

Comment: Perhaps you have "Keep iTunes media folder organized" disabled?  I've edited my answer to reflect this.